# how can I understand if the phones are really rebooted adb

Tags: android, linux, adb

Im trying to reboot the devices and really check that they are really rebooted. I tried to use uptime like this: `adb s device id uptime` 
but didnt work .

Comment: Your code is awful but that can be helped. What is much worse - it is completely irrelevant to the question (I think) you are trying to ask. Then you claimed that some command did not work for you but you did not explained how exactly it failed nor provided the expected result.

Comment: Yes ,actualy you are right .I could explain my problem better.

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose of checking device's uptime the following command provides data in a format which is much easier to work with:

```
adb -s <device_id> shell cut -d' ' -f1 /proc/uptime
```

But checking the device's uptime immediately after reboot is pointless - the device would not be available. So it would make more sense to check the local USB device enumeration instead.

Comment: it gave me this error:"more than one device , emulator.Also how can I check the local USB device enumeration ?

Comment: I was hoping that you would know that you need to provide the specific device id for your `adb` commands when you have multiple devices connected